# NavBar not working in Bootstrap using integrity parameter in link

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to include NavBar in my html code, but it is not succeeding since the integrity parameter in the link statement is posing a problem.

I have included to change the integrity parameter to other values, yet the problem persists.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gamja+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrapcdn.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected a perfect NavBar to be displayed.
It instead results in an ordinary unordered list.

Comment: where is body tag ?

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I have made the required changes. It did not make any difference yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your bootstrap links to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gamja+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to add the navbar class in CSS file?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by adding navbar class in CSS file. Could you give me more details?

Comment: What should I enter after the "." in CSS to specify the navbar class?

Comment: I would say `.navbar` but there are more than 1 elements included in Bootstrap navbar. You can take a look at your HTML code, or simply use DevTools (F12 or right-click the navbar and choose Inspect option) in your browser to check class for the element you want to style.